# Can't figure out how to use $(this) correctly in jQuery to get hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, this, show

So I have several DIVs called achievement, and each one contains a span called recent-share. WHat I would like to do is have each recent-share hidden at first, and the have it appear when the parent 'acheivement' class is hovered. I'm trying to use $(this) to get it, but it won't work. I'm assuming this is a syntax error or something, and any help would be appreciated!

```
<script>
    $(".recent-share").hide();
    $('.achievement').hover(
        function ()) {
            $(this).next(".recent-share").show();
          });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$( ".achievement" ).hover( function() {
    $( this ).find( ".recent-share" ).show();
});
```

Also you had a syntax error – it should be `function () {`, not `function()) {`.

Answer (score 1):

`.next()` targets a sibling. Try:

```
<script>
    $(".recent-share").hide();
    $('.achievement').hover(
        function ()) {
            $(this).find(".recent-share").show();
          });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try one of thes 3 ways:

**1. children() lookup**

```
$(this).children('.recent-share')
```

**2. context lookup**

```
  $('> .recent-share',this)
```

**3. find()**

```
$(this).find('> .recent-share') // is basically the same as nº2
```

Not tested, had this in my snippets.